# Bootstrap Layout Issue from StringBuilder

Tags: html, css, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am still learning Bootstrap and I am working on a layout that gets generated by a VB.NET page using a StringBuilder. I get a messed up layout as seen in the picture:

[image: Layout issue]

It gets worse in other parts of the page. It seems like Bootstrap doesn't like that the items are not the exact same size.

Here is my code:

```
sb.Append("<div class=""row""><div class=""col-md-12""><img src=""http://placehold.it/1000x225"" /></div><!-- col-md-12--></div><!-- row -->")
sb.Append("<div class=""row thuumbnails"">")
If dr.HasRows Then
    Do While dr.Read
        sb.Append("<div class=""col-md-2"">")
        sb.Append("<div class=""img-thumbnail"">")
        sb.Append("<a href=""#"" class=""thumbnail""><img src=""http://placehold.it/100x100"" /></a><h4 class=""thumbnail caption"">" & dr.Item("PrdName") & "</h4>")
        sb.Append("<center>" & dr.Item("PrdCode") & "</center><br />")
        sb.Append("<center>Price: " & dr.Item("PrdPrice") & " MSRP: " & dr.Item("PrdMSRP") & "</center>")
        sb.Append("</div><!-- thumbnail --></div><!-- col-md-2 -->")

    Loop

    sb.Append("</div><!-- row -->")

Else
    ' No data returned so send a message to the front end
    sb.Append("<div class=""col-md-12""><div class=""warning"">There were no categories to display!</div><!-- col-md-12 --></div><!-- warning -->")
End If
```

All the CSS is straight Bootstrap code. Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening and how I should fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ultimately come to the conclusion that Bootstrap itself has no way of dealing with this issue, so I have resorted to some Javascript that helps with this problem. Here is the code I used:

```
<script>
       function equalHeight(group) {
           tallest = 0;
           group.each(function () {
               thisHeight = $(this).height();
               if (thisHeight > tallest) {
                   tallest = thisHeight;
               }
           });
           group.each(function () { $(this).height(tallest); });
       }
       jQuery(document).ready(function () {
           App.init();
           equalHeight($(".img-thumbnail"));
       });
   </script>
```

This goes through and max the max-height of all the DIVs with class img-thumbnail be the same as the tallest DIV on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before as well, try re-uploading all of the files, JS, CSS, HTML, etc. Also, make sure it's being hosted on a server, it seems to make my bootstrap function better.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not fix the problem.

Comment: Are you attaching via bootstrap website or a downloaded file thru bootstrap?

Comment: I downloaded through Bootstrap. After your suggestion I went ahead and got another download and replaced the files. No change at all. I am now wondering if something is messed up in my HTML so I am going to run that through a validator.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but for the ones that will come before me try something like:

```
htmlStr.Append("<li class='list-group-item'>"+ detail.Key + ": " + detail.Value + "</li>");

class=' ' and not class=" "
```

That worked for me.